# What does grep -v _1_ <file_name> do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to bash scripting, can someone tell me what is the meaning of the below command.

```
grep -v _1_ <file_name> > <new_file>
```

Comment: At least on GNU `grep` you could run `help` like this `grep --help | grep -- ' -v'`

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions should explain exactly what aspect of the code you're asking about, and what research you did (and what you learned from that research -- and, pointedly, what questions you still have, so we don't reexplain things you found in that research that aren't actually helpful).

Comment: Please read the manual page for grep with `man grep`, then look for the paragraph explaining all options (or search within `man` by typing `/-v` to look for -v).

Answer (score 2):

The `-v` switch inverts the criteria, so it shows only the lines which does NOT contain the string `_1_` and logs the output into the file `<new_file>`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is wrong, you have written the command as:

```
grep -v _1_ <file_name> > <new_file>
```

While it should be:

```
grep -v _1_ <file1> > <file2>
```

You can use `grep` on more file than one, which means that you are looking for something in more than one file.

The `-v` part is already explained by Antonio.